# How do attachments that add damage effects to projectiles work?

Tags: dead-space-3

I'm trying to optimize the DPS and effectivity of my weapons. With that goal in mind, I would like to know how attachments that add damage effects to projectiles work.

Those attachments are:

- [Electric Charge](http://www.ign.com/wikis/dead-space-3/Electric_Charge)
- [Flame Glaze](http://www.ign.com/wikis/dead-space-3/Flame_Glaze)
- [Acid Bath](http://www.ign.com/wikis/dead-space-3/Acid_Bath)
- [Damage Support](http://www.ign.com/wikis/dead-space-3/Damage_Support)

I would like to know:

- How do these attachments compare to each other in terms of damage added to each projectile?
- How do they add damage?

  - Is it a multiplier or a constant amount added per projectile?
  - Are there attachments that will work better with low per projectile damage, high rate of fire weapons; instead of high per projectile damage, low rate of fire weapons, and vice-versa?
  - How do they stack with Upgrade Circuits that increase damage?
- What are their effects on enemies? Does the enemy react differently, depending if the projectile that hit them comes with electricity, flame or acid?

Comment: Sorry, I just had to update my answer again, because my experiments seem to be wielding contradictory results sometimes. One thing is certain: damage support is weaker than the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been experimenting on the attachments that add damage out of curiosity, and here's what I've observed. All these tests have been performed inside the Weapon Crafting Arena on "Impossible" difficulty and against the [dog necromorph (which acts like the babies in Dead Space 1)](https://deadspace.fandom.com/wiki/Lurker).

**TL;DR:**

- Damage support bonus is very negligible.
- Having twice the same attachement doesn't mean it will stack stack (2 Damage support or 2 Ammo support won't give any more than 1).
- Electric charge, Flame gaze and Acid bath all do DOT (Damage Over Time). They don't stack, but they benefit from shooting slower, although shooting fast won't neglect their effect entirely either.
- The "Full Zoom Scope" gives the equivalent of a +1 Damage circuit to both upper and lower tip, so it's not very noticeable either.

If you have a very fast weapon with an insane damage output and an insane ammo capacity, you might as well go with Stasis coating. If you spray, by the time they reach you, they're done; unless it's an axe necromorph, in which case you'll have to wait for it to break into pieces before you can kill it (shooting it when it didn't break yet is a waste of ammo, because stasis will slow down the transformation, making it invulnerable as long as you shoot).

---

Both the normal, the MK-II and the MK-V variants give the same kind of damage bonus, so I will omit that detail (the MK variants usually give bonus in the kind of Reload speed, Clip size and Rate of fire).

- Weapon: Plasma cutter.
- Upper tool tip: Planetcracker.
- Upper tool upgrade circuit: 4 times +3 Rate of Fire and +3 Damage (total: +12 damages).

Experiments:

- Attachments: 2 Damage support; necromorph died in 4 shots.
- Attachments: Damage support and Flame gaze; necromorph died in "3 shots". I actually had to wait for the flame to kill it after the 3rd shot.
- Attachments: Damage support and Electric charge; necromorph died in 3 shots.
- Attachments: Electric charge; necromorph died in 3 shots. This means the bonus from the Damage support is quite negligible in comparison to Electric charge (which is weaker than Flame Gaze and Acid Bath). Unless you're shooting a weapon with lots of ammo against a tough target, you're better off with something else.
- Attachments: Full Zoom Scope (equivalent of +1 Damage circuit) and Electric charge; necromorph died in 3 shots. Not much of a difference on a target that dies too fast, I guess. **Edit:** Not much difference noticed by combining with Damage support, Flame gaze nor Acid bath.

Out of curiosity, I also tried equipping 2 Ammo support, and having 2 didn't give any more bonus than if I had only 1, which means they don't stack; same for Damage support. I suspect if you play with a coop partner, they won't stack with your partner's attachment either if they have the same. The only thing that does stack is the ammo bonus you get from them being MK parts.

The experiments above were tested without paying attention to shooting speed. Below, I tried shooting faster and slower:

- Attachments: Electric charge; shot relatively fast; necromorph died in "3 shots". I actually had to wait for the electricity to kill it after the 3rd shot, which means electric damage isn't instantaneous, contrary to what I thought.
- Attachments: Electric charge; shot as fast as I could; necromorph didn't die after the 3rd shot and the electric damage, but died instantly to the 4th shot. This means that, despite the electric damage being "faster" than fire and acid, since I shot too fast, every next shot discarded the previous electric damage, rendering it useless until I stopped shooting.
- Attachments: Electric charge; used stasis 4 times and shot slower; necromorph didn't die after the 3rd shot and the electric damage, but died instantly to the 4th shot. This means stasis will slow down the DOT too. **Edit:**  After redoing the same test, it doesn't seem so. Might have missed a shot somewhere.
- Attachments: Flame gaze; waited until the flame effect disappeared before each shot; necromorph still dies in "3 shots". I suspect it would work better with Damage support and Acid bath by waiting until the acid effect wears off between each shots. **Edit:** After redoing the same test, the necromorph dies instantly to the 3rd shot. Maybe I shot too fast the first time. It looks like the damage between fire and acid isn't so far apart; perhaps the same.
- Attachments: Flame gaze; shot relatively fast; necromorph died instantly to the 3rd shot.
- Attachments: Flame gaze; 2 fast shot, waited for the flame to disappear; necromorph died instantly to the 3rd shot.
- Attachments: Acid bath; waited until the acid effected disappeared before each shot; necromorph died instantly to the 3rd shot.
- Attachments: Acid bath; used stasis 4 times and shot slower; necromorph didn't die after the 3rd shot and the acid didn't work, but died instantly to the 4th shot. It almost feels like stasis prevent DOT damage entirely. **Edit:** After redoing the same test with fire and acid, it doesn't look like stasis affects them in any way. Might have missed a shot somewhere.
- Attachments: Acid bath; shot as fast as I could; necromorph died in "3 shots". I actually had to wait for the acid to kill it after the 3rd shot. It's hard to tell whether or not it stacks under those conditions.
- Attachments: Flame gaze; shot as fast as I could; necromorph died to the "3rd shot" due to fire damage, but not as fast as with acid.
- Attachments: Electric charge; shot as fast as I could; necromorph died to the "3rd shot" due to electric damage, about as fast as fire, even though some previous tests showed fire was stronger.
- Attachments: 2 shots without Acid bath then 3rd shot with Acid bath; necromorph didn't die in 3 shots even after the acid effect

I don't have enough evidence to say whether or not they stack, but electric, fire and acid damages seem to be working to some extent even when shooting a weapon fast. One thing is sure: they're all damaging over time, and acid lasts the longest and seems to do the most damage.

Out of curiosity, I dumped all the Damage circuit and replaced the Planetcracker tip with a default tip to keep damage as low as possible. Upon shooting various parts of the different necromorphs' body (Slasher and Leaper for example), the effect was visible all across and not just where the last shot landed. It's possibly stacking, but I felt like necromorphs died faster when I shot slower when playing the campaign, so you should follow your guts. Personally, I'll use it for a weapon that doesn't shoot too fast/not a full auto one.

**Edit:** I tried a slightly weaker Plasma cutter with moderate full auto capacity (+9 Damage circuit, +9 Rate of fire with Compact Directed Ejection Field for the full auto ability) with Flame gaze, and this time I shot into the back of a Slasher. 7 shots of full auto didn't kill it and it died to the 8th shot instantly. However, shooting 7 individual shots, waiting for the flame to disappear, did kill it 1 shot faster.

I guess shooting too fast will make the DOT weaker, but not render it useless.

---

As for how much damage they give, I can't give any figures. I can only guess that, unlike the Full Zoom Scope which gives a visible bonus similar to a +1 Damage circuit, Damage Support seems to be dependent on how much damage your weapon has, although the bonus from the Damage support is so negligible that, by the time you get it to give a significant bonus, your weapon would be already so strong that it could kill anything nearly instantly.

As for the others (Electric charge, Flame gaze and Acid bath), I would like to believe that it's the same, because when you remove all your Damage attachment, the DOTs aren't capable of killing necromorphs as fast. The only thing I can tell for sure is: Acid lasts longer than Flame, which lasts longer than Electric, and Flame does more damage than Electric too, but seems to be doing nearly as much damage as Acid.

If you can't afford to watch the necromorphs approaching you while it's damaging them, you're better off using these attachments on slower weapons or using different attachments.

Comment: A small detail I haven't mentioned because I think it's pretty obvious: DOT doesn't help in breaking limbs, and they don't work if the shot landed on a limb that broke because of it.

Answer (score 1):

Flame = a very short duration DoT with an initial damage that does not stack, better used on fast firing weapons like pulse rifles or the plasma cutter.

Acid = a very long duration DoT that stacks, good on VERY fast firing weapons like flamers. A Few enemies are imune to this mod.

Shock = almost no damage but stuns the enemies for a few moments, good on high powered weapons that lack the stun effect like the sniper rifle (military engine+precision tip).

Damage support = increases the damage for about 5% for both players and stacks (10% for both), (this is an educated guess as no one knows the exact number, not worth using the flame gaze is more effective on any situation, the weapons that would benefit from this increase already kill everything in 1 shot like the contact beam, using an ammo box is way more effective for example).

Extra things you should know:

DoT stops knock back effects when it ticks, like the force gun, so avoid using these mods on Crowd control weapons, the stasis moule is designed for them.

Avoid using the stasis module on explosive weapons if you are not using safe guard, the stasis effect will also apply on you from your own shots.

Hope this helps.